# Ubuntu grub rescue mode to boot windows without a recovery disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, grubrescue

So I have had this old laptop and I had two operating systems loaded on it; one being windows 7 the other Ubuntu.

I deleted Linux off of it. It gave me grub rescue menu when it rebooted.

Learning from other question on here, I tried booting from a usb and was able to get into windows from there. While I was in Windows, I deleted the two partitions that both said that they had 100% unused space. After that, I was going to make a recovery disk, however I had no disks and it restarted on me in the middle of the night. I tried to reboot from usb and do the boot-repair, but it is no longer working.

How can I access and boot into Windows now from the grub rescue menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access/boot into Windows now because the information required by GRUB to do that has been deleted along with the partition.

You need to boot Windows installation media or recovery media to fix the Windows bootloader.